# Compressional wave in a cube

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, physics, compression

I want to see the propagation of a compressional wave in a cube. I meshed a cube along Y and just added wave in this same direction as follows:

[image: Screenshot of wave]

But only the first and the last Y normal surfaces move while the rest of the cube remains completely still. How do you get all the surfaces to move to illustrate the propagation of a compression/dilatation wave through the cube?

Comment: You may have to delete the surrounding geometry, that is all the short edges.

Comment: i do not think that this is possible...but...surprise me! ;)

Comment: In which direction do you want the compression? Longitudinal (along Y), or transverse (in XZ) ?

Comment: longitudinal, along Y. For transverse it's ok.

Answer (score 16):

For illustration, you could pass an Empty down the length of the cube, create a vertex group in the cube, (say, 'Prox',) and give the cube a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier, modifying the weights in the group by the proximity of the Empty.

Here, we see the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier, affecting the 'Prox' group, targeted on the plain-axis Empty, and the consequent weights (made visible in the 'Overlay' settings,in Edit Mode).

[image]

Those weights can then be used to control other modifiers. For longitudinal compression, you could parent a plane to the Empty, and give the cube a Shrinkwrap modifier, projected in + and - of the length-axis (mine is X) towards the plane, weighted by the 'Prox' group:

[image]

If, for example, you wanted a leading compression front, rather than contraction on both sides of the plane, you could get the shrinkwrap to project on one side only.

This, though, is as shown:

[image]

For transverse compression, you could use a *Displace* (along normals) modifier instead of the shrinkwrap.. no need for the plane:

[image]

If you needed something more mathematically exact, I'm sure there will be a Geometry Nodes solution. For that, maybe you could provide your wave function.

[image]

Comment: Warp modifier could let you skip the proximity, if what you want is just a loc/rot/scale transformation.

Comment: Hi @Nathan! I'm not very experienced with _Warp_ .. please post an answer if you have time, if not , I'll have a play with it when I do.

Comment: Woooooowwwwwwwww

Comment: It kind of demands animation demo, and I've never figured out a good, easy enough way to show that here-- do you viewport render and convert to gif using a different application?  Gif is so painful....

Comment: @Nathan is right.. _Warp_ gives you the choice of a custom falloff curve, which might be just what would suit this case. I use [Bligify](https://github.com/doakey3/Bligify) to convert viewport animations (Linux)

Comment: Hi and thanks Robin. could give you a concrete explanation of the steps to be taken if you have time. I'm trying to figure out empties, weights, and groups, and I'm having a hard time combining these ideas to do what you did.

Comment: @Newenda See Edit.

Answer (score 8):

A warp modifier is a nice way to do this:

[image]

It measures the transformation from one empty to another empty, and then applies the transformation to the mesh in a given radius, with a specified, even custom curve, falloff.  The radius is measured from the "object from" object, which can then be animated along the length of the curve.  I typically parent the "to" object to the "from" object.  The scale of the "to" object is shown in my sidebar; that's the transformation the mesh is undergoing.

[image]

Comment: Cheers! Must get my head round this one.

Comment: Hi Nathan, nice idea. Where is your second empty on your example ? thx

Comment: They're both at the same location.  Both are selected in the still; the active selection is the "to" and the secondary selection is the "from."

Comment: tks, But in the blender new version, empty properties is different and dont offer the same menu at all... and cant find a tuto about that.. https://i.goopics.net/JqKra.png

Comment: The modifier isn't on the empty, it's on the mesh.  That's version 2.92, the latest release, and there haven't been any differences to empties for a long time anyways.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the very functional answers already here, I would use a **Lattice** modifier with a moving Lattice object.

This allows for not only compression waves, but also transverse waves and even spacially asymmetric combinations of transverse and compression waves with arbitrary waveforms:

[image]

Comment: I honestly don't know why my answer is attracting so much UV.. I think both yours and @Nathan's suit the OP better. You have to play with the lattice a bit, to understand the difference between transforming it in Edit and Object mode, but in the end it can do everything in my answer, more simply.