# animate Scaling part of an object driven by another object

Tags: modeling, animation, displacement, dynamic-paint

So the idea is, i want to animate "Scale" an object driven by another object

**visual representation:**

1. [image] 2. [image]

its kinda hard to describe, but i want an object/empty to drive an object's scale / displacement / deform

What I have tried:

1. I tried using the dynamic paint to drive the weight map, and use that data to deform / displace
2. Using shape keys

if anyone have better way to do it, i'll love to hear them

thanks !

Comment: Consider Cast Modifier and Shrink Wrap Modifier.  At least the established jargon for these two modifiers may help you to pose your question.

Comment: possibly related: [Compressional Wave in a Cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222811/compressional-wave-in-a-cube/222828)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Consider using a cast modifier.

Make sure you original mesh has many vertices.
Use the object field to determine the origin.
The object field can be an empty to control the origin.
When you move the empty the displacement will move also.
If your axis is World Z axis aligned you may choose to keep z unchanged in the modifier.

More to follow.

Consider also using a shrink wrap if you want more control over the modified shape.  Not yet shown.

[Create slanted end at a pipe / cylinder by Rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50753/create-slanted-end-at-a-pipe-cylinder-by-rotation/50757#50757)

I do not know your artistic vision for the deformation.  Here is a less smooth modification.

[image]

[image]